# Recorrer y modificar cada ítem de una columna eficientemente

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataset de 213080 filas y 20 columnas, yo quiero hacer una modificación sencilla a las entradas de una columna en particular, algo como

```
for i in range(len(Datos['lugar'])):    
    Datos['lugar'][i]=Datos['lugar'][i][0:-1]
```

dónde la columna lugar contiene cadenas.

El problema es que con la longitud de `Datos['lugar']` es 213080, mi computadora dura mucho haciendo la modificación. Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay una manera mas eficiente de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato tienes almacenado en la columna `lugar`?

Comment: Tipo string, pero tambien haré lo mismo con otro que es tipo entero.

Answer (score 2):

En general, nunca uses un ciclo `for` crudo de Python para recorrer un DataFrame, es posiblemente la forma más ineficiente de iterar sobre una columna para modificarla, solo debes recurrir a ello en casos muy específicos en los que se hace imprescindible contar con la naturaleza dinámica de Python. Pandas está pensado y optimizado para vectorizar este tipo de operaciones.

Suponiendo que tu columna lugar sea de tipo `str`, lo que deseas es eliminar el último carácter de cada elemento de la columna, es mucho más sencillo que lo que planteas:

```
Data["lugar"] = Data["lugar"].str[:-1]
```

Si generamos un pequeño ejemplo con una columna de 10000 cadenas podemos comparar ambas aproximaciones (tiempo de ejecución medido en consola IPython con `%%timeit`):

```
import pandas as pd


Datos = pd.DataFrame({"lugar": ["España\n", "Argentina\n", "Colombia\n",
                             "Chile\n", "México\n", "Ecuador\n"] * 10000})

%%timeit
for i in range(len(Datos['lugar'])):
    Datos['lugar'][i]=Datos['lugar'][i][0:-1]
```

> ```
> 17.9 s ± 2.16 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
> ```

```
%%timeit    
Datos["lugar"] = Datos["lugar"].str[:-1]
```

> ```
> 11 ms ± 251 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
> ```

**17.9 segundos frente a 11 mili-segundos**, no hay mucho que discutir.

La misma idea se aplicaría para otros tipos de datos, por ejemplo si queremos a una columna sumarle otra y elevarla al cuadrado podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": (2, 13, 7, 5),
                   "b": (5, 4, 3, 11)})
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       a   b
> 0     2   5
> 1     13  4
> 2     7   3
> 3     5  11
> ```

```
df["a"] = (df["a"] + df["b"]) ** 2
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>      a     b
> 0   49     5
> 1  289     4
> 2  100     3
> 3  256    11
> ```

### **Bonus**

En referencia a la duda planteada en el comentario si tienes una cadena y quieres quedarte solo con la parte que va desde el principio hasta que encuentra un determinado carácter tienes varias posibilidades. Vamos a partir del siguiente ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

Datos = pd.DataFrame({"hora": ["14:20:05", "02:14:03", "17:53:26"]})
```

> ```
> >>> Datos
>
>           hora
> 0     14:20:05
> 1     02:14:03
> 2     17:53:26
> ```

- **`pandas.Series.str.split`:**

  Es una adaptación del método `str.split` de Python, en este caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

  ```
  Datos["hora"] = Datos["hora"].str.split(":")[0]
  ```
- **`pandas.Series.str.partition`:**

  Igual que el anterior pero parte la cadena en la primera aparición del carácter.

  ```
  Datos["hora"] = Datos["hora"].str.partition(":")[0]
  ```
- **`pandas.Series.str.extract`:**

  En este caso hacemos uso de una expresión regular. Esto nos da una flexibilidad enorme ya que nos permitirá buscar patrones muy complejos.

  ```
  Datos["hora"] = Datos["hora"].str.extract(r"(.*?):")
  ```

En cualquier caso obtenemos:

> ```
> >>> Datos
>
>     hora
> 0     14
> 1     02
> 2     17
> ```

Otra opción es parsear la cadena como `Datetime` y manejarla como una fecha directamente.

Comment: Me ha funcionado muy bien lo que dices, gracias. Una duda mas. Yo quiero modificar una columna en específico con parte de lo que ella tiene a partir de que salga cierto caracter en especial en cada fila, sería algo asi .   for i in range(len(Datos['hora'])):
    

    Datos['hora'][i]=Datos['hora'][i][0:Datos['hora'][i].index(':') ] Esto quiere decir que tome desde el inicio hasta que aparezca el caracter dos puntos (:). ¿Como hacerlo de manera mas eficiente?

Comment: @user9608539 he editado la respuesta, al final de ella tienes varias posibilidades para conseguir lo que quieres si te he entendido bien.