# Modificar entradas de un dataframe pandas grande

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Yo tengo un dataframe de 213080 filas y 15 columnas.
Yo quiero modificar una columna en específico con parte de lo que ella tiene a partir de que salga cierto caracter en especial en cada fila, sería algo asi . 
`for i in range(len(Datos['hora'])):
    Datos['hora'][i]=Datos['hora'][i][0:Datos['hora'][i].index(':') ]`

Esto quiere decir que tome desde el inicio hasta que aparezca el caracter dos puntos (:). ¿Como hacerlo de manera mas eficiente?

Comment: ¿No es esta pregunta muy similar a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/258981/7123)? ¿No puedes aplicar la misma técnica que te dieron allí?

Comment: Aunque en este caso igual era mejor convertir la columna a tipo `datetime` (usando `pandas.to_datetime()`) para después poder quedarte con el campo que te interese, con algo como `Datos.hora.dt.hour`

Comment: Es similar pero tiene algo distinto, necesito saber el indice de donde aparece el simbolo de dos puntos según cada elemento. Para hacer esto, yo había hecho Datos['hora'][i].index(':') pero tengo que volver a iterar un for con el i.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma directa es usar el método `str.split()` de esa columna.

Por ejemplo, si los datos son:

```
data = {
    "hora" : [ "13:01", "14:25", "15:22", "15:45", "16:23", "18:30"],
    "valor": [3, 6, 8, 9, 20, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    hora  valor
0  13:01      3
1  14:25      6
2  15:22      8
3  15:45      9
4  16:23     20
5  18:30      2
```

Lo que propongo sería:

```
df.hora = df.hora.str.split(":", expand=True)[0]
```

Eso separa la hora por los dos puntos, y con el `expand=True` crea dos columnas, una para la hora y otra para los minutos, y con el `[0]` nos quedamos con la de las horas solamente.

Pero creo que en este caso sería más lógico (aunque quizás no tan rápido) tratar la columna "hora" como de tipo `datetime`, lo cual nos da acceso a sus campos, a través del atributo `dt`. En este caso sería:

```
df.hora = pd.to_datetime(df.hora).dt.hour
```

En cualquiera de los dos casos obtendrías lo mismo:

```
   hora  valor
0    13      3
1    14      6
2    15      8
3    15      9
4    16     20
5    18      2
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la columna detalle tiene mucha informacion, tiene la hora y muchas cosas mas, por eso yo solo quiero quedarme con la hora, para eso estoy usando que vea donde estan los dos puntos y tome dos valores antes y dos valores luego.

Comment: Pero no estás haciendo eso, estás tomando desde el índice 0 hasta el índice en que aparecen los dos puntos. Por tanto entiendo que la hora es lo primero que aparece en la cadena, y por tanto el método de hacer `split(":")` y quedarte con la primera columna resultante también debería servirte. Si la hora no está al principio, mejor especificas cómo es la información que tienes en esa columna, pues podría resolverse con una expresión regular.